# memory not released WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, memory-leaks

I have developed a sample WPF application that has one window with one button
When application is opened, if observed from task manager, memory occupied: 12.3 MB

```
Dim b As Boolean = False
Private lst As List(Of String)
Private Sub Btn_Close(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If b = False Then
        If lst Is Nothing Then lst = New List(Of String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 30
            lst.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(IO.File.ReadAllBytes("d:\test.txt"))) 'memory increases, test.txt file is a 2MB file
        Next
        'do some operations with lst object
        'memory occupied: 133MB
        'now again click the same button, it will go to else case now (cause of the last statement)
    Else
        lst.Clear()
        If MsgBox("GC.Collect()?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            GC.Collect()
            'in this case, memory occupied: 13MB
        Else
            'in this case, memory occupied: 133MB, not cleared
        End If
    End If
    b = Not b
End Sub
```

Only when GC.Collect() statement is executed memory is released, otherwise the memory stays at 133MB only.

I have requirement in a way when click on any button, a new window opens as showdialog that contains a grid with thousands of records, say: 6000 to 1Lakh, here I do some operations with the selected records (here memory increases) and then closes the window. After closing the window, the memory is not released, I explicitly have to execute the statement GC.Collect()

Is there any thing wrong in the code? or why do I need to explicitly call GC.Collect as CLR will take care of it automatically? (in my application, if I repeat above and don't use GC.Collect, I get outofmemory exception after some time)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code, and there's nothing wrong with your memory consumption either. There is no guarantee that closing your form will immediately release the memory; indeed, GC will reclaim the memory when *it needs to*, which is very often not when a developer *expects* it to.

Garbage collection in .NET fires automatically in response to *allocations of memory* - that is, when you try to declare an object that doesn't fit in the heap's current Gen0, a garbage collection will occur.

The real question to ask here is: why do you have an issue with the memory staying at 133MB? Is it causing you a problem? Unless you have a specific requirement for this memory to be collected, I'd say *don't* `GC.Collect()`, and let the framework work it out for you.

(It's worth noting that calling `GC.Collect()` manually often has a *negative* effect on the long-term memory consumption of an application.)

Comment: in my actual application it would take around 800MB if there are more number of records in the grid, and get outofmemory exception for the next time(it reaches around 980MB), I'm using 32-bit machine and application is built under x86

Comment: No, it won't: when you *allocate* that memory, your GC will probably fire automatically. GC will release the memory *when your application needs it*, not when you close the form. If you're getting out-of-memory exception (when you're not calling `GC.Collect`) then you likely have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Sandeep - I would question whether loading 6000+ records into a datagrid is a good design.  No user will want to page through all those records.